Azure function publish slot "Error when removing app settings"
I have a function app and I just created a slot called development. When I try to deploy code to the slot with:
func azure functionapp publish <function app name> --slot development

I get the following output and error:
Removing WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING app setting.
Removing WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE app setting.
Error when removing app settings: {"Code":"InternalServerError","Message":null,"Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":null},{"Code":"InternalServerError"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"InternalServerError","Message":null}}],"Innererror":null}.

I tried deleting and recreating the slot with a different name but it did not work.
I am using the latest az and Azure Functions Core Tools cli versions
I am afraid deleting the environment variables myself in case they affect production. [ref]

Can you provide your sample code and specify the language you're using for deployment?

I created a sample function and added a slot. I encountered the same error when I tried to publish the function to the slot.


To fix the error, we need to delete the WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE settings in the slot, but we can't directly delete them in the slot.


So, I deleted those settings in the main Function app as shown below.

Then, I swapped the Target slot changes with the Source slot changes.

So that the WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE values are not present in the development slot.

And those will be swapped into the main function app's environment variables.

After swapping, the WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE values will not be present in the target slot

After making all the above changes, I have successfully deployed a sample HTTP trigger function in Python to the development slot.
func azure functionapp publish kamfuncappslot --slot development



development slot :
I successfully got the function in the development slot.

